# Five 1-inch furnace filters vs. One 5-inch furnace filters

Tags: hvac, air-filter

What would be the issue if I quintupled the furnace filters (16x25x1) MERV8 instead of installing the regular 5-inch (16x25x5) MERV8 in the filtration box? I'm finding the cost savings is considerably less with 5 1-inch filters versus a single 5-inch filter.

Comment: why would you want to install five 1 inch filters when the 5 inch filter is cheaper?

Comment: The question is contradictory to me.  Could you please rephrase it

Answer (score 2):

The issue would be pressure drop. Each 1 inch filter will create a pressure drop, and they don't exactly add up, but they do stack. High pressure drop will cause worse performance of your heating equipment, higher energy usage, and perhaps poor heat distribution.

1 inch filters actually have a higher pressure drop than 5 inch filters, because they have less filter area. So a single 1 inch filter will create more pressure drop than a single 5 inch filter. A stack of five of them will cause a lot of pressure drop.

If you want to use a 1 inch filter, just use the one inch filter by itself. Your equipment probably has a slot to hold it. If you want to use a better filter, use a 5 inch filter. It probably will have a longer lifespan and thus a lower total cost.